# VB.NET using class library from service

Tags: vb.net, service, .net-assembly

I have created a class library (Namespace aaa) which contains some public classes. Now I want to create a windows service which uses some of the types defined in that class library. I am adding a reference to the assembly (resp. the project) to the service project, import the corresponding namespace and try to use one of these classes. When building the service project, Visual Studio complains **"Namespace or type specified in the Imports '`<qualifiedelementname>`' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found"**.
The project containing my unittests, which uses the same class library, does work without any problems. What am I doing wrong or what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the namespace show up in auto-completion when you type "Imports<space>"?

Comment: No it doesn't. However, the types show up when I do type "Private mSomething As aaa." and syntax highlighting and code navigation works. As soon as I try to build it fails.

Comment: Strange. Just a shot in the dark: Did you try "Clean Solution" and then rebuilding?

Comment: Yes, I already tried. The strange thing is, that I can use the class library from my unittest project but not from within the windows service project. I even tried to recreate the service project, adding a reference to the class library but had the same issue. I even have the same problem creating a simple windows form application and trying to use the class library. :/

Comment: I have created new projects, pasted all code, changed some names at now it does work. Probably the problem was that the name of the dll was the same as the Namespace and there could have been some issue resolving names. But I didn't have had time to check and reproduce it. So as soon as I know how to do, I would like to close the question. Many thanks, Heinzi, for your time and all the best to the greatest city on earth, Vienna, where I have lived for almost 5 years.